# npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sequelize@6.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"}

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

```json
{
  "name": "express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "Pratik Ahirrao",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

i want to install sequelize in my nodejs application.

I am getting this error:-

```
npm install --save sequelize
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sequelize@6.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sequelize@6.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sequelize-pool@6.0.0: wanted: {"node":">= 10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sequelize-pool@6.0.0

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...4e5abc2adff5fa18def",'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pratik/.npm/_logs/2020-06-24T08_25_07_274Z-debug.log
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem .
My node(8.10.0) was not compatible to install sequelize.
So i upgraded it to the latest version.
Here are the commands to upgrade your node to the latest version using `n`:-

```sh
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
```

Comment: VERY BAD. NEVER `sudo npm`

Comment: @Zach why not sudo? They are trying to update the system-global (`-g`) node engine.